# IFRAME app is running out of facebook layout

Tags: facebook, web-applications, facebook-iframe, facebook-apps, facebook-canvas

My IFRAME application is out of facebook layout. My app opens in a new browser tab, with the Facebook bar on top, oauth at center of the page, and ticker on right panel, but the left panel with user info (like pages, apps, etc) isn't there.

I want my app to open inside the facebook layout, like a page tab, I don't need more space than that.

Changing my app's config did not resolve the problem. The only basic settings I've checked is "App on Facebook", the advanced settings are for canvas width "fixed(760px)", canvas height "fluid".

How can I keep my IFRAME application inside the Facebook layout? The app can have only 520px width.

Answer (score 0):

You should not create App on Facebook. What you are asking is Page Tab.

Comment: Não, I dont want page tab! Page tab I have to my page, I need is App!

I just dont need 760px and inside facebook layout! Now I know it's impossible! Thanks anyway!